# I cannot get this LEFT JOIN to work (I don't understand joins)

Tags: sql, join, intersystems-cache

These queries both get results:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria = '5'
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria = '3'
```

This query gets results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 p, Table2 m
WHERE p.UID = m.ID
AND Criteria = '5'
```

This query does not:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 p, Table2 m
WHERE p.UID = m.ID
AND Criteria = '3'
```

I am trying to convert these to a proper join which returns results even if there are no records in the right table.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 p LEFT JOIN Table2 m ON p.UID = m.ID
WHERE p.Criteria = '3'
AND m.OtherCriteria = 'Moron'
--0 results
```

My limited understanding was that LEFT join is what I needed.  I want data from the *left* table even if there is no data in the *right* table that matches.  Since this didn't work I also tried `right join`, `left outer join`, `right outer join` and `full join`.  None returned results.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're saying it looks right?  Probably Caché... :(

Comment: From your first observation (`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria = '3'`) it is already clear why your LEFT JOIN is "not working".

Comment: Enlighten me please?

Comment: In this case, try to understand the LEFT JOIN as an optional set of columns (the ones from Table2) to be appended to the main set of columns (from Table1). Optional in the sense that if they don't exist, they won't supress any row. But, if the main query (from Table1) already has no rows, nothing to do then.

Comment: @rslemos read his post again and include the first line in your understanding -- he states `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria = '3'` **returns rows**

Comment: Weird. Early I've read "returns no rows". So sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  Your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 p LEFT JOIN
     Table2 m
     ON p.UID = m.ID AND p.Criteria = '3';
```

Should be returning a row for all rows in `table1`.  If there is no match, then the values will be `NULL` for `table2`.  This is easily demonstrated: [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/33967) is a MySQL example on SQL Fiddle.  Because this is standard behavior, it should work on almost any database.

Note that this query is quite different from this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 p LEFT JOIN
     Table2 m
     ON p.UID = m.ID 
WHERE p.Criteria = '3';
```

This query returns no rows, because no rows match the `WHERE` clause.  The filtering happens (conceptually) *after* the `LEFT JOIN`.

I changed the code in the SQL Fiddle slightly, so that query is:

```
select *
from (select 5 as criteria, 1 as id union all
      select 6, 1 union all
      select 7, 2
     ) table1 left join
     (select 1 as id, 'x' as x
     ) table2
     on table1.id = table2.id and criteria = 3;
```

As a note:  you should always use explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

If your database is returning no rows, then it is behaving in a non-standard manner or your interface has decided to filter the rows for some reason.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.  Let me try to clarify my question, sorry.

Comment: Okay I updated.  Sorry it was confusing to start, hopefully better now.

Comment: He said that the p.Criteria = '3' with no join does return rows so it does not matter to his question (or it shouldn't) if he uses the where.

Comment: @ScottBeeson . . . The explanation is still accurate, although the emphasis is different.  It doesn't matter why the `on` clause returns not-true.  All rows in the first table should still be returned.  The conclusion remains the same:  Cache is not implementing standard behavior for the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I agree, the only explanation is a typo and what is the OP is showing here is actually NOT what is run.  This difference accounts for the issue.

Comment: That's possible.  I will see if I can desensitise the data and edit the post instead of using a pseudo query.  It looks accurate though...

Comment: Also, here is the Cache documentation on a one-way join: http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20101/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_join#RSQL_C35983

Comment: I had an additional piece of criteria in the query with the JOIN.  /facepalm

Comment: I reflected this in the original question.  Perhaps you can modify your answer to point out that I have criteria defined for the right table that affected the query